# Adonis 5 + Vue "E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, adonis.js

I'm doing an Adonis v5 app with Vue 2 as frontend.
My problem is, once I've build Vue frontend into public adonis folder. If I access to a speficic route writing it into the top browser searcher, I get the E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND from Adonis.

I do think that adonis is trying to search the route into the router of the server and not into the Vue router. Althought adonis it's configured to use static files and the first frontend page works:

Vue router.js:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
{
 path: "/",
 redirect: { name: "acceso" },
},
{
 path: "/acceso",
 name: "acceso",
 component: SignupView,
 meta: { guestAllow: true },
}];

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: "history",
 routes,
});
```

Adonis routes.ts (It shouldn't affect as the have a prefix:

```
Route.group(() => {
  Route.group(() => {
    Route.post("register", "AuthController.register");
    Route.post("login", "AuthController.login");
  }).prefix("auth");
  Route.group(() => {
    Route.get("logs", "LogsController.index");
  }).middleware("auth:api");
}).prefix("/api");
```

Adonis static.ts:

```
import { AssetsConfig } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Static'
const staticConfig: AssetsConfig = {
 enabled: true,
 dotFiles: 'ignore',
 etag: true,
 lastModified: true,
 maxAge: 0,
 immutable: false,
}
```

[If I write localhost:3333 on the browser I redirects to /access (Correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBY5i.png)

[But if I refresh the page, or browse manually the same route, the error shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xwfO.png)

Any idea of what could it be?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking some other projects on internet, I've seen that if you use `mode: "history"` on vue-router it pops the error.

So I've tried to comment this line and now I can refresh the page without `E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND` error.

Frontend Vue router.js:

```
const router = new Router({
  //mode: "history",
  routes,
});
```